# Log4j.properties and log4j2.xml

Tags: log4j2

Is it necessary to have both `log4j.properties` and `log4j2.xml` in a maven project to print logs to file?

Or is `log4j2.xml` sufficient?

Comment: I assume you're using [automatic configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration). If that is the case then do you mean log4j2.properties? A file named log4j.properties would not be used by log4j2 when using the automatic configuration, but it would used by log4j1 automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`log4j2.xml` alone is sufficient.

Or, `log4j2.properties` alone would also be sufficient.

Note that if both `log4j2.properties` and `log4j2.xml` files are present on the classpath, `log4j2.properties` "wins". Or you can explicitly define which configuration file to load using the `log4j.configurationFile` system property.

See Log4j2 manual for details: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: when I alone use log4j2.xml, it give error "No appenders could be found for logger". Is there anything I am missing out ?

Comment: Potential problems are: 1. the `log4j2.xml` isn't on the **root** of the classpath, 2. the `log4j2.xml` is there, but its contents are wrong/incomplete (e.g. no appenders defined for the **root logger**?), 3. there's a conflicting log4j2 configuration file on the classpath (e.g. log4j2.yml).